# Syslog-ng log rotation

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, event-log

i have a problem with syslog-ng rotate system.

I need that my file rotation is schedule one time a day, example :

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  37K Oct 16 192.168.40.240.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  83K Oct 15 192.168.40.240.1.log.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  50K Oct 14 192.168.40.240.2.log.gz
```

But now the result is :

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  28K Oct 16 06:23 172.20.252.15.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  37K Oct 16 06:21 192.168.40.240.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  38K Oct 16 06:21 192.168.40.241.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 5.3K Oct 16 06:57 192.168.50.229.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  76K Oct 16 06:21 192.168.50.240.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 241K Oct 16 07:04 192.168.50.241.log
```

Content of the file /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng

```
/var/log/zlog/*.log
{
        rotate 3
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}

/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
/var/log/error
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks